# How to hide and show elements on the same event listener

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to hide and show a `div` on the same eventlistener. I'm able to hide the element but not show it back again. This is what I have tried so far.

```js
var hidebox = function() {
  document.getElementById('box').setAttribute("class", "hidebox");
  document.getElementById('bd').setAttribute("class", "newButton");
}

var showbox = function() {
  if (document.querySelector('.newButton')) {
    document.getElementById('box').removeAttribute("class", "hidebox")
    document.getElementById('bd').removeAttribute("class", "newButton")
  }
}

document.getElementById('bd').addEventListener('click', hidebox)
document.getElementById('bd').addEventListener('click', showbox)
```

```css
.hidebox {
  display: none;
}

.box1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.box2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<img id="bd" src="pic.jpg">
<div class="box1" id="box"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
```

Comment: you want to create one `toggle` function and bind that, rather than a separate show and hide function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just used 5 LINES..I think this is the Easiest way to do it :)

```js
function reveal() {
  if (document.getElementById("box").style.display === "none") {
    document.getElementById("box").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("box").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.hidebox {
  display: none;
}

.box1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.box2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<img id="bd" onclick="reveal()" src="https://placehold.it/25x25">
<div class="box1" id="box"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a toggle you could use `classList.toggle`.

```js
var toggleBox = function(){
  document.getElementById('box').classList.toggle("hidebox");
  document.getElementById('bd').classList.toggle("newButton");
}

document.getElementById('bd').addEventListener('click', toggleBox);
```

```css
.hidebox{
    display: none;
}

.box1{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

.box2{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<img id="bd" src="https://placehold.it/25x25">
<div class="box1" id="box"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
```

Comment: I ended up using this solution. This works very well on responsive layouts.